# Is VS2015 C++ profiler usless when it comes to getting line numers/functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, profiler

I wanted to test out VS2015 C++ profiler and since it was crashing on creating detailed report I have upgraded VS2015 to Update1.
Still now when I click on profiling and after it is done to create detailed report and
select Current View: Functions 
It only shows MyExecutable.exe instead of functions
when I do select Current View: Lines
It shows the same(executable name) and no lines, and helpfully Source line begin and other related columns all show 0.

Additionally it complains
Failed to load symbols for C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
Although I have checked Microsoft Symbol Servers in the symbol settings.

So basically what I am asking are people able to obtain C++ profiling information using VS2015 Update1 on Win7 or is it just a buggy feature that does not really work.

Comment: If you are using an intel chip there is an intel profiler that works much better than visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons is that symbols are not resolved successfully for MyExecutable.exe. Please ensure that:

- You can set and hit breakpoint when debugging your application.
- There is no "Failed to load symbols" log message for MyExecutable.exe when opening detailed report.
- Function names are shown in call tree of CPU Usage tool ([this](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/45/92/metablogapi/0211.CPUReport_Annotated_773668DF.png) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC717114.jpeg) screenshot clarify what I mean).